# Pattern to create polymorphic objects with dependency constraint

Tags: java

First, my structure :

AbstractObject
--ObjectA
--ObjectB

AbstractOtherObject
--OtherObjectA
--OtherObjectB

With polymorphism, I want to create an `AbstractOtherObject` based on my `AbstractObject`. More precisely, I want an `OtherObjectA` if it is an `ObjectA`, and same for B.
The important point is that I don't want  a dependency to `AbstractOtherObject` in `AbstractObject`. I can't make an abstract method`AbstractOtherObject toOtherObject()` in `AbstractObject`.

I can't find a solution that doesn't use **instanceof**.

Thanks in advance.

Update : pseudo code

If I didn't have the dependency constraint I would do this :

```
public class Any{
    void do(AbstractObject o){
        AbstractOtherObject otherO = o.toOtherObject();
        doSomething(otherO);
    }
}
```

But since I don't want a dependency, I am only able to do something ugly like :

```
public class Any{
    void do(AbstractObject o){
        AbstractOtherObject otherO;
        if(o instanceof ObjectA){
            otherO = new OtherObjectA(o);
        } else {
            otherO = new OtherObjectB(o);
        }
        doSomething(otherO);
    }
}
```

Comment: Some pseudo code of how you'd want to use that might be helpful. At least I have some difficulty in understanding what it is that you actually want.

Comment: You can not return an AbstractOtherObject from an AbstractObject without incurring a dependancy on AbstractOtherObject in AbstractObject.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visitor pattern to the rescue!

```
public class VisitorExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ConverterVisitor converterVisitor = new ConverterVisitor();
        A a = new A();
        B b = new B();
        a.accept(converterVisitor);
        AbsOther aother = converterVisitor.getOther();
        b.accept(converterVisitor);
        AbsOther bother = converterVisitor.getOther();
    }
}
```

The gist is to let a separate class in this case ConverterVisinor do the actual work of converting between the types.

The Visitor class needs to know about the different concrete classes that should be visited, but the Visitable just needs to have a dependency to the Visitor interface.

```
interface Visitor {
    void visit(A a);
    void visit(B b);
    void visit(Visitable visitable);
}

interface Visitable {
    void accept(Visitor v);
}
```

So the visitor that does the actual work of converting between the types would look something like:

```
class ConverterVisitor implements Visitor {


    // Added field and getter to store the other object in...
    private AbsOther other;

    public AbsOther getOther {
        return other;
    }

    public void visit(B b) {
        System.out.println("Convert a to BOther");
        other = new BOther();
    }

    public void visit(A a) {
        System.out.println("Convert a to AOther");
        other = new AOther();
    }

    @Override
    public void visit(Visitable visitable) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Type: " + 
            visitable.getClass().getName() + " not supported");
    }

}
```

Then the Abstract classes and classes that are involved in the conversion can look like:

```
abstract class Abs implements Visitable { }
abstract class AbsOther { }

class A extends Abs {

    public void accept(Visitor v) {
        v.visit(this);
    }

}

class B extends Abs {

    public void accept(Visitor v) {
        v.visit(this);
    }

}

class AOther extends AbsOther {

}

class BOther extends AbsOther {

}
```

If you can't add anything to the concrete classes you would need to wrap them in a type aware Visitable wrapper.

**EDIT:**
To get the converted Other object you have two possible solutions. Either you could make the visitor statefull (see above). Alternatively you could use a Generic Visitor/Visitable if you need your acceptor method to return a value.

```
public class VisitorExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AConverterVisitor converterVisitor = new AConverterVisitor();
        A a = new A();
        B b = new B();
        AOther aother = a.accept(converterVisitor);
        System.out.println("Got AOther!");

        try {
            b.accept(converterVisitor); 
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException iae) {
            System.out.println("Calling accept on b with a AConverterVisitor will result in a exception");
        }

    }
}
```

Visitor and Visitable are now generic:

```
interface Visitor<T> {
    T visit(A a);
    T visit(B b);
    T visit(Visitable visitable);
}

interface Visitable {
    <T> T accept(Visitor<T> v);
}
```

ConverterVisitor is abstract and is subclassed to a concrete visitor on a per type basis:

```
abstract class ConverterVisitor<T> implements Visitor<T> {

    public T visit(Visitable visitable) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Type: " + visitable.getClass().getName() + " not supported");
    }


    public T visit(A visitable) {
        return visit((Visitable) visitable);
    }


    public T visit(B visitable) {
        return visit((Visitable) visitable);
    }

}

class AConverterVisitor extends ConverterVisitor<AOther> {

    @Override
    public AOther visit(A a) {
        return new AOther();
    }

}
```

A and B's accept method would now be implemented like:

class A extends Abs {

```
public <T> T accept(Visitor<T> v) {
    return v.visit(this);
}
```

}

class B extends Abs {

```
public <T> T accept(Visitor<T> v) {
    return v.visit(this);
}
```

}

And the other classes and abstract classes would be same as in the first example.

Comment: It seemed fine to me, since you could have the `Visitor` interface in the `A` and `B` package, and the `ConverterVisitor` in the `AOther` and `BOther` package. However, you do need to get back your new `AOther` instance. Thus, your visit method in the Visitor returns an `AOther` and you have the dependency.

Comment: Added a generics version and how to implement the converter as a statefull converter. See edit.

Comment: Thanks. I think that the statefull converter should work but the generic one can't be used in my case, because I don't know in the first place if I call `.accept` on a `A` instance or a `B` one. I test your first solution ASAP.

Answer (score 0):

Not a perfect solution, but it is better [IMO] then using `instanceof`, is a variation of [abstract factory pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern).

Create `AbstractOtherObjectFactory` abstract class, and concrete classes: `OtherObjectAFactory`, `OtherObjectBFactory`.

Populate a `Map<Class,AbstractOtherObjectFactory>`: that maps all possible classes that extends `AbstractOtherObject` to their relevant factory.

when need to create a new object use: `map.get(obj.getClass()).build(obj);`

Note that `AbstractObject` and its derived classes are not dependeding on any of the `AbstractOtherObject` and its derived classes, and you eliminate the usage of `instanceof` - but at the cost of using `getClass()`.

**Example:**

First type of classes:

```
public abstract static class AbstractObj {
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "AbstractObj";
    }
}
public static class A extends AbstractObj {
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "A";
    }
}
```

second type of classes:

```
public abstract static class OtherAbstractObj {
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "AbstractObj";
    }
}
public static class OtherA extends OtherAbstractObj {
    public OtherA(AbstractObj obj) { }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "OtherA";
    }
}
```

factory classes:

```
public static interface Factory {
    public abstract OtherAbstractObj build(AbstractObj obj);
}
public static class OtherAFactory implements Factory {
    @Override
    public OtherAbstractObj build(AbstractObj obj) {
        return new OtherA(obj);
    }
}
```

populate a map [needed to be done only once in the program life time]:

```
    Map<Class<? extends AbstractObj>,Factory> map = new HashMap<Class<? extends AbstractObj>, Test.Factory>();
    map.put(A.class, new OtherAFactory());
```

create a new second type object from the original:

```
    AbstractObj a = new A();
    OtherAbstractObj other = map.get(a.getClass()).build(a);
    System.out.println(other);
```

(*)Note that you will still need to cast in `public OtherA(AbstractObj obj)` if you actually need the `A` features. You can use access modifiers to make sure that `otherA` can be created only using its factory.

(*)This solution is not perfect, but it should work. A better solution will be obviously creating a `createOtherObj()` method, as you mentioned - but it requires dependecy on `AbstactOtherObject`

Comment: Well, ok. You use a pre-constructed Map to avoid the ifs statements and you use a key instead of instanceof. It is nicer, but that's the same flawed concept. Maybe there is no other solution. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @D0m3 I agree this solution has its issues.. but that is the best I could think of that obey the "no dependecy constraint"

Comment: Yeah. I wait a bit to see if there are other answers, otherwise I'll choose yours.